# Checking for divide by zero

Tags: c++, algorithm

In my program, given a random number of random operations using a random numbers ex. 2 + 5 / 2 - 5 + 2 * (9 - 5) / 2
-- I need to check if there will be a divide by zero error when calculating the numbers. How would I do this, and without getting an error myself?

code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < randNumOfOperations; i++) {
    int randDecision = rand() % 5 + 1;
    int randDecision2 = rand() % 4 + 1; // inside () operations
    int randDecision3 = rand() % 4 + 1; // outside () operations
    int randNum = rand() % 15 + 1;
    int parenRandNum = rand() % 20 + 1;
    int parenRandNum2 = rand() % 20 + 1;
    std::string tempstr = std::to_string(randNum);
    std::string tempstr2 = std::to_string(parenRandNum);
    std::string tempstr3 = std::to_string(parenRandNum2);
switch (randDecision) {
        case 1: 
            nStr.append(tempstr);
            nStr.append(" + ");
            break;
        case 2:
            nStr.append(tempstr);
            nStr.append(" - ");
            break;
        case 3:
            nStr.append(tempstr);
            nStr.append(" * ");
            break;
        case 4:
            nStr.append(tempstr);
            nStr.append(" / ");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (randDecision == 5) { //( ) operations
        nStr.append(" (");
        switch (randDecision2) {
        case 1:
            nStr.append(tempstr2);
            nStr.append(" + ");
            nStr.append(tempstr3);
            break;
        case 2:
            nStr.append(tempstr2);
            nStr.append(" - ");
            nStr.append(tempstr3);
            break;
        case 3:
            nStr.append(tempstr2);
            nStr.append(" * ");
            nStr.append(tempstr3);
            break;
        case 4:
            nStr.append(tempstr2);
            nStr.append(" / ");
            nStr.append(tempstr3);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        nStr.append(") ");

        switch (randDecision3) {
        case 1:
            nStr.append(" + ");
            break;
        case 2:
            nStr.append(" - ");
            break;
        case 3:
            nStr.append(" * ");
            break;
        case 4:
            nStr.append(" / ");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

The code puts the random expression into the string nStr.

Comment: How are you evaluating the expression? If you're parsing it and processing the parse tree, you can check at each divide node whether the divisor is zero.

Comment: I'll bite. Why do you need this?

Comment: updated the post with my code to generate the expression.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't show anything about how you are _evaluating_ the expression. That's where the checking has to be done.

Comment: Rather than general parsing consider the rather straight forward conversion of your infix expression to a postfix(or prefix-notation if you would rather) for which basic math such as this is very well suited. Again it would be rather simple to check at that point if you will be dividing by zero at such point. Also as pointed out, how you are evaluating the expression is the key as that will provide the means to avoid the issue.

Comment: my program places the string in a different source file. that source file is then compiled and executed, and the expression will be evaluated. sorry if that doesnt answer i am stupid.....

Comment: You'll need to modify your generating code to do the evaluation internally. If it detects a divide by zero, it would then reject the string and generate a new one without writing it to the source file. So instead of a generate-and-write loop, you have a generate-test-and-maybe-write loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would look into how to build an expression tree and evaluate the expression using that. It would make it simple to check for divide by zero and it would be efficient. You could also use this for many different applications in the future. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expression-tree/

Answer (score -2):

to check once u have it all parsed an if statement with 0 will return false

```
if(devisor)
result=result/devisor;
```

i have a similar project done on github
[for a recursive approach](https://github.com/Mike-Fink-Jr/CS122-Data_Structs/tree/master/Compiler_HMWKs/Math_Ops-Recursion)
[using a list and stack](https://github.com/Mike-Fink-Jr/CS122-Data_Structs/tree/master/Compiler_HMWKs/Math_Ops-List_%26_Stack)

Comment: How can you assume tokenizing when  the are clearly parens in the expression ?

Comment: u can make a function double oper(double a, char operator, double b)

Comment: That does not answer anything at all.

Comment: u have to run it recursively, check it out on my github   https://github.com/Mike-Fink-Jr/CS122-Data_Structs/tree/master/Compiler_HMWKs/Math_Ops-Recursion

Comment: (a+b)+c/(d*e) after recursing and before resolving would look like oper(oper( a , + , b ) , + , oper(c , /, oper( d, * ,e)))    @MadPhysicist